# mysql trigger not working right anymore

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

My trigger all of a sudden stopped working.  It was working fine and now it is only half way working.  The trigger was concatenating the particular columns I coded it for, but now for one of the columns (an auto increment PK) its just outputting that column as a zero but everything else is fine.

```
create trigger insert_trigger
before insert on bids
for each row
set new.opportunity = concat(new.dueDate," - ",new.serialNumber," - ",new.organization," - ",new.description);

create trigger update_trigger
before update on bids
for each row
set new.opportunity = concat(new.dueDate," - ",new.serialNumber," - ",new.organization," - ",new.description);
```

I have no idea what the issue could be.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> My trigger all of a sudden stopped working.

As of myself I would say your trigger suddenly start working as expected :D

---

More seriously, `auto_increment` fields don't have value until the row is inserted.

It is strange you could have accessed that auto_increment value in your `BEFORE` trigger, obtaining anything else that 0.

Maybe you could switch to an `AFTER INSERT` trigger?

---

OTOH, if you *really* need access auto_increment value from your *before* trigger, try using that in your trigger:

```
Set ai = (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME='tbl')
```

I don't know however how this will behave regarding of concurrent insert into your table.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a value for an `auto_increment` column is not available in `BEFORE` event since the row is not being inserted yet, and in `AFTER` event you can no longer change `NEW` values.

Now you can overcome this problem by introducing a separate table for sequencing purposes.

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE bids_seq 
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE bids
(
  serialNumber INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT 0, 
  dueDate      DATE, 
  organization VARCHAR(32), 
  description  VARCHAR(32),
  opportunity  VARCHAR(64),
  ...
);
```

Now your triggers:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_bids_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON bids
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO bids_seq VALUES (NULL);
  SET NEW.serialNumber = LAST_INSERT_ID(),
      NEW.opportunity = CONCAT_WS(' - ',
                                  NEW.dueDate,
                                  NEW.serialNumber,
                                  NEW.organization,
                                  COALESCE(NEW.description, ''));
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CREATE TRIGGER tg_bids_after_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON bids
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.opportunity = CONCAT_WS(' - ',
                                  NEW.dueDate,
                                  NEW.serialNumber,
                                  NEW.organization,
                                  COALESCE(NEW.description));
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9943/1)** demo